# How to fetch key based on values from app.config file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an app.config file like this:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="botLogs" value="d:\TFS Projects-BotLogs/"/>
    <add key="botfolder" value="C:\BOTSCONFIG"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=1.1.1.1;Database=BGAppCrawling;UID=sa;Password=something;" name="VGDB"/>
    <add connectionString="Server=1.1.1.1;Database=BGMappingStaging;UID=sa;Password=something;" name="VGDBMapping"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Now I can fetch values based on keys in appSettings section like this:-

```
string filePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["botLogs"].ToString();
```

But what is the way if I want to fetch key based on values from appSetting section ?

Comment: Do i understand it right but you want to find the key by searching for the value?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(string key in System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings)
{   
 var key = key.ToString();   
 var value = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings[key.ToString()];
 //Do something here
}
```

or

```
var settings = System.Web.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings;

var value = from string k in settings.Keys
            where k.StartsWith("MyValue")
            select settings[k];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following `GetEnumerator method` based code :

```
NameValueCollection values = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
Iterate(values);    
public void Iterate(NameValueCollection myCollection)
{
    IEnumerator myEnumerator = myCollection.GetEnumerator();
    Console.WriteLine("KEY VALUE");
    foreach (String item in myCollection.AllKeys)
    Console.WriteLine(" {0,-10} {1}", item, myCollection[item]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (string key in Configuration.AppSettings.Settings.AllKeys)
        {
            string value = appSettings.Settings[key].Value;

            if (value.Equals(myValue))
            {
                 Console.WriteLine("Found Key: " + key);
                 break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i would say that you should replace your keys with values and the values with the keys,

```
<add  key="d:\TFS Projects-BotLogs/" value="botLogs"/>
<add  key="C:\BOTSCONFIG" value="botfolder"/>
```

thanks
rakesh